# Filter based on multiple date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

The user clicks on a month and then this stored procedure is executed. It checks for the total booked time and what groups have been filtered.

```
 | Job Group | Month Booked | Time (hrs) |
   Cleaning        Jan            7
```

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    tsks.grouping_ref, ttg.description AS grouping_desc, 
    SUM(ts.booked_time) AS booked_time_total, 
    DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm) AS month_name,
    @month_ref AS month_ref
FROM 
    timesheets ts
JOIN  
    timesheet_categories cat ON ts.timesheet_cat_ref = cat.timesheet_cat_ref
JOIN 
    timesheet_tasks tsks ON ts.task_ref = tsks.task_ref
JOIN 
    timesheet_task_groupings ttg ON tsks.grouping_ref = ttg.grouping_ref
WHERE 
    ts.status IN(1, 2) --Booked and approved
    AND cat.is_leave_category = 0 --Ignore leave
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, ts.start_dtm) = @Year
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, ts.start_dtm) = @Month
GROUP BY 
    tsks.grouping_ref, ttg.description,
    DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm),
    DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm)
ORDER BY 
    grouping_desc
```

I want to filter based on multiple date ranges.

I thought about adding this:

```
AND ((ts.start_dtm BETWEEN '2011-12-28' AND '2012-01-01')
OR (ts.start_dtm BETWEEN '2012-01-02' AND '2012-01-29'))
```

But then realized it wouldn't matter what month the user clicked it would still show all the records as it will carry out the OR statement.

What I need is something that's based on the month_ref, eg:

```
CASE WHEN @month_ref = 81201 THEN 
AND (ts.start_dtm BETWEEN '2011-12-28' AND '2012-01-01')
END
```

But the case statement needs to go just after the WHERE clause.

I have about 12 accounting months for 2012 which I need to add as case statements so that when the user clicks on March, it will fire the correct filter.

In the database `ts.start_dtm` looks like this:

```
2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
```

Hope that was enough information for my first post?

I'm stuck writing the case statement and where to put it, been trying for hours now.

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the irregular nature of your dates would preclude using dateparts; I would build a temporary table of the permissible dates based on the user query and join on it. The static integers table in my app has 1 through 64000 your tables may vary.

```
DECLARE 
    @startdate DateTime  = '2012-05-01',
    @EndDate DateTime = '2012-06-03'

DECLARE
    @AllDates TABLE (MyDate DateTime)

INSERT INTO @AllDates
SELECT 
    DATEADD(dd, StaticInteger, @startdate)
FROM dbo.tblStaticIntegers
WHERE StaticInteger <= DATEDIFF(dd, @startdate, @EndDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, so your code snippet creates the temp table in my DB?

Comment: The example uses a temporary table to store the dates that the query would run against yes. You will need to create a permanent table of  integers to let the insert statement work (assuming you don't already have one)

Comment: My stored procedure seems to work in management studio but the website doesnt seem to like DATE BETWEEN. Any ideas why?

Comment: In the first instance I would run profiler and check the dates that are being passed in are in the format you would expect

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a table mapping the month reference number to a start and end date thus retrieving those values and using them in your ts.start_dtm check.  ie it would have:

Month-ref | Start | End
81201 | 2011-12-28 | 2012-01-01
81202 | 2012-01-02 | 2012-01-29

etc

You can just join to this reference table or alternatively retrieve the two dates before your main query